# Diffusion Equation with Non-constant coefficient

Tags: python, numerical-methods, pde

I am trying to solve a diffusion equation numerically:

dT/dt = k(x) d^2T/dx^2

say k(x) = x^2

x and t ranges from 0 to 1

**IC**: *T(x, t = 0) = 0*
**BC**: *T(x=0,t) = 0, T(x=1, t) = 1*

I wrote the code below, but it is giving wrong results

```
import numpy as np
L =1
n = 100
T0 = 0
T1s, T2s = 0, 1
dx = L/n
alpha = 0.001
t_final = 1
dt = t_final/n

x = np.linspace(dx/2, L-dx/2, n)
T = np.ones(n)*T0
print(T.shape)
dTdt = np.empty(n) #initializing the 

t = np.arange(0, t_final, dt)
tt = np.zeros((100, 100))
tt[0] = T
for j in range(1, len(t)):
    for i in range(1,n-1):
        dTdt[i] = x[i]**2*(-(T[i]-T[i-1])/dx**2 + (T[i+1]-T[i])/dx**2)
    dTdt[0] = x[0]*(-(T[0]-T1s)/dx**2 + (T[1]-T[0])/dx**2)
    dTdt[n-1] = x[n-1]*(-(T[n-1]-T[n-2])/dx**2 + (T2s-T[n-1])/dx**2)
    T = T + dTdt*dt
    tt[j,]= T
```

Where am I getting it wrong? Thanks.

I tried solving it numerically but the results were wrong cos I got blown up values which are greater than the ranges of T

Comment: Welcome to [so]. We don't provide debugging services. The following references give advice on debugging your code. [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/), [Six Debugging Techniques for Python Programmers](https://medium.com/techtofreedom/six-debugging-techniques-for-python-programmers-cb25a4baaf4b)  or [Ultimate Guide to Python Debugging](https://towardsdatascience.com/ultimate-guide-to-python-debugging-854dea731e1b)